# Is it possible to set a struts token with a GUID as a token name?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, token, ognl

I'm trying to set a struts token in a form with a unique name for each form. Is there way to set up the token in a way like `<s:token name="<some random generated characters>"`. I was planning to use the TokenHelper.generateGUID() to generate the token name, if possible. I've tried setting a variable using `<s:set var="tokenName" value="<%=TokenHelper.generateUID()%>"/>`, then setting the token using `<s:token name="${tokenName}"/>`. I'm getting tld error about setting the in the  tag. Here is the general code flow of the form.

here are the things that i've tried, but got the same result.

```
   <%@ page import="org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper" %>

   <s:form action="actionName_method" name="actionName" method="post">
     <s:token name="<%=TokenHelper.generateGUID()%>"/>
     <s:hidden ....
     .... rest of the fields go here ....
     <s:submit value="save" name="submit"/>
   </s:form>
```

Another one I tried is,

```
    <%@ page import="org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper" %>
    <s:set var="tokenName" value="${f:generateGUID()}"/>
    <!-- I defined generateTokenName as a tld function using the TokenHelper class -->
           <s:form action="actionName_method" name="actionName" method="post">
             <s:token name="${tokenName}"/>
             <s:hidden ....
             .... rest of the fields go here ....
             <s:submit value="save" name="submit"/>
           </s:form>
```

Here is the my definition of the function f:generateGUID() in the tld file.

```
    <function>
        <description>This will generate the a unique tokenName</description>
        <name>generateGUID</name>
        <function-class>org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.String generateGUID()</function-signature>
    </function>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) as well.

Comment: Another note, I've tried using the f:generateGUID() like by just displaying the content using <c:out value="${tokenName}"/> or something along like this and it displays a the random keys. Does it maybe process the s:token tag before it generates the random keys using the function I'm using( f:generateGUID())?

Comment: @Braj Do I just replace the TokenHelper with the UUID and use UUID.randomUUID() instead of TokenHelper.generateGUID?

Comment: Sorry I don't have much experience on `Struts`. I just told you an another way to generate the random key in JAVA. Might be someone will help you that experts in Struts. Just wait for some time.

Comment: @Braj The other way is also possible. Is a token name should be a random key?

Comment: Why do you need to change token name to guid?

Comment: @AleksandrM If the same type of form is opened in two tabs, it invalidates the  one that was opened first and just saves the most recent one. Also i've discovered that since some forms we have supports a "save and create another" function that creates some sort of a glitch. If the "save and create another is clicked multiple times very fast, the token in the session doesn't match the token in the form. Therefore, the token validation results to false.

Comment: @Braj I see, I will keep the UUID as an option in the tokenName generation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to set a token name with

```
<s:token name="%{tokenName}"/>
```

It will generate two hidden fields one for the token name and another for the token value. Make sure the value of the first field corresponds to the name of the second field.

The action property `tokenName`  is initialized like

```
tokenName = TokenHelper.generateGUID();
```

or

```
tokenName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Also make sure the form is using `POST` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. A follow up question, what's the difference between using %{}, ${} and #{} when when setting an attribute?

Comment: In JSP `%{}` is used in struts tags to force OGNL to evaluate an expression enclosed in brackets, `${}` is used for EL expression, and `#{}` stands for a `Map` creation.