# Token Interceptor with annotation not working properly

Tags: jsp, struts2, token, interceptor, double-submit-problem

I am using a submit button to save data and to avoid double submission i am using `token` interceptor.

I am using Struts annotation instead of XML configuration.

Without token my form is working well and on submit it is saving data, but when i use `token` interceptor then data is not saved.

Can anyone please help me out.

**My syntax for Action is:**

```
@Action (value = "/addNewHolidaySave",results = 
{ @Result(name = "success", location = "addHoliday.tiles", type = "tiles"),
  @Result(name = "invalid.token", type = "tiles", location = "invalidToken.tiles") },
 interceptorRefs={
      @InterceptorRef("token"),
      @InterceptorRef("basicStack")
})
```

Comment: Note that the [token interceptor wiki page](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/token-interceptor.html) specifically states you should use the token tag. It's good to read the docs; it makes asking questions like this unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid double submission you should place [`s:token` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/token-tag.html) in the body of the form. While rendering it will generate two input fields with data needed to proceed your form submision with [`token` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/token-interceptor.html) applied.

You might also find these answers useful to you: [Is it possible to set a struts token with a GUID as a token name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24231081/573032) and [How Token Interceptor work in Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808701/573032).